# Silverlight Issue with Firefox 3.6?

Tags: silverlight, plugins, silverlight-3.0, firefox3.6

Recently I updated my  firefox to 3.6 and the silver light app on my web app has weird behavior.

No button click happens in the silverlight app, it just gives it the focus and if we 'TAB' around, we can get the click working. But this is not like the previous behavior in FF 3.5.7. Very inconvenient for the unsuspecting users.

This would definitely be a pain for customers upgrading to FF 3.6, as they wouldn't know why the button click is not working. I believe this has also effected Silverlight showcase site as well.

Wanted to know if there has been any updates in this regard. I want to get this fixed ASAP. I can only suggest my customers to downgrade/hold FF update, for now.

Comment: Have tried installing the Silverlight 4 Dev Tools to see if you have the same issue with the developer version of SL4?

Comment: I've just been to the http://silverlight.net showcase page and it seems to be having a problem with the cursor positioning. There seems to be a vertical offset being applied.

Comment: Haven't checked SL4. I think its SL plugin issue with FF 3.6 or vice verse. This SL app is a small part of the web-app I am looking for know issues (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Could check if there is a stacked div above the silverlight area..? Its all I can think of without seeing an example.

Comment: It has the following tags
<div style="height: 80%;" id="XamlHolder">
        <span id="Xaml1_parent"><object style="height: 320px; width: 249px;" id="Xaml1" type="application/x-silverlight-2">
...</object>
</span>
</div>

Does this tell you anything. I am noob in silverlight and just know enough to get by for the time being.

Comment: spans are normally inline elements, so you could try changing the spans to divs and see if that helps..?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the problem you mention but Silverlight and FF 3.6 definitely have issues. My application when it gets focus, FF displays vertical and horizontal scrollbars for the whole window.

Same application in IE8 and Chrome, no problems.

Answer (score 0):

try this

a:focus, object:focus {
outline: none;
}

the issue is described here:
http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/forum/1/564700

however, what i cannot fix is the flickerring of the screen when there is a browser scrollbar (resize the window to less my minimum size) and scroll up and down.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is related, but I recently installed firefox 3.6.6. (this was the first time that firefox was ever installed on this machine). I am running SL4. Now my Silverlight app won't run at all...

The xap file is loaded because I get to the login screen but then it crashes with a "plugin-container.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close" error.

This app worked fine in previous versions of firefox.

Anyone else have this issue?